# How to simulate fisheye lens effect by openCV?

Tags: opencv, simulate, fisheye, distortion, radial

I am looking for ways to create fisheye lens effect, looked at documentations for openCV, it looks like it contains Camera Calibration functions for radial distortions like fisheye. Is it possible to simulate fisheye distortion by openCV?

If it is possible to do it by openCV, comparing to openGL, which one will generate better results? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I created [this app](http://faces.splintec.com/) using opencv. Is this the effect you are referring to?
I basically coded the formula shown on wikipedia's "Distortion(optics)" I can show the code if needed

**Update**:
OK, so below is the actual code written in c++ using opencv (not documented so feel free to ask for explanations):
The program recieves as input the following parameter: |*input image*| |*output image*| |*K which controlls amount of distortion (typically try values around 0.001)*| |*x coordinate of center of distortion*| |*y coordinate of center of distortion*|

So the crux of the program is the double *for* loop which iterates pixel by pixel on the result image and looks for the matching pixel in the input image using the formula for radial distortion (this is the way image warping is generally done - perhaps counter intuitively by back-projection from output to input). There are some subtleties which have to do with the scale of the output image (in this program the resulting image is the same size as the input), and I won't get into it unless you want to get into more details.enjoy.

```
    #include <cv.h>
    #include <highgui.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <getopt.h>
    #include <iostream>


    void sampleImage(const IplImage* arr, float idx0, float idx1, CvScalar& res)
    {
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(cvGetSize(arr).height-1) || idx1>(cvGetSize(arr).width-1)){
        res.val[0]=0;
        res.val[1]=0;
        res.val[2]=0;
        res.val[3]=0;
        return;
      }
      float idx0_fl=floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=ceil(idx1);

      CvScalar s1=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      CvScalar s2=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      CvScalar s3=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      CvScalar s4=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);
      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;
      res.val[0]= s1.val[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[0]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[0]*x*y + s4.val[0]*x*(1-y);
      res.val[1]= s1.val[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[1]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[1]*x*y + s4.val[1]*x*(1-y);
      res.val[2]= s1.val[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[2]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[2]*x*y + s4.val[2]*x*(1-y);
      res.val[3]= s1.val[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[3]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[3]*x*y + s4.val[3]*x*(1-y);
    }

    float xscale;
    float yscale;
    float xshift;
    float yshift;

    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float thresh = 1;
    float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){
      float x3 = x1+(x2-x1)*0.5;
      float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
      float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

      //  std::cerr<<"x1: "<<x1<<" - "<<res1<<" x3: "<<x3<<" - "<<res3<<std::endl;

      if(res1>-thresh and res1 < thresh)
        return x1;
      if(res3<0){
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
      }
      else{
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
      }
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      IplImage* src = cvLoadImage( argv[1], 1 );
      IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth,src->nChannels);
      IplImage* dst2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth,src->nChannels);
      float K=atof(argv[3]);
      float centerX=atoi(argv[4]);
      float centerY=atoi(argv[5]);
      int width = cvGetSize(src).width;
      int height = cvGetSize(src).height;

      xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,K);
      float newcenterX = width-centerX;
      float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,K);

      yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,K);
      float newcenterY = height-centerY;
      float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,K);
      //  scale = (centerX-xshift)/centerX;
      xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
      yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;

      std::cerr<<xshift<<" "<<yshift<<" "<<xscale<<" "<<yscale<<std::endl;
      std::cerr<<cvGetSize(src).height<<std::endl;
      std::cerr<<cvGetSize(src).width<<std::endl;

      for(int j=0;j<cvGetSize(dst).height;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<cvGetSize(dst).width;i++){
          CvScalar s;
          float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,K);
          float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,K);
          sampleImage(src,y,x,s);
          cvSet2D(dst,j,i,s);

        }
      }
    #if 0
      cvNamedWindow( "Source1", 1 );
      cvShowImage( "Source1", dst);
      cvWaitKey(0);
    #endif

      cvSaveImage(argv[2],dst,0);

    #if 0
      for(int j=0;j<cvGetSize(src).height;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<cvGetSize(src).width;i++){
          CvScalar s;
          sampleImage(src,j+0.25,i+0.25,s);
          cvSet2D(dst,j,i,s);
        }
      }

      cvNamedWindow( "Source1", 1 );
      cvShowImage( "Source1", src);
      cvWaitKey(0);

    #endif  

}
```

Comment: Yes! Barrel distortion on Wiki's "Distortion(optics)" page is exactly what I am looking for! I would like to know how to map an image around fisheye lenses with openCV. Can you show your code here? Or show me some hints? Thank you.

Regards

Comment: I tried to understand the code, but am slightly held back, with many operations that I do not know why they occur. Is it possible to add a short brief or description?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the above 2 for this code. I've modified the above transcribed code in Java to use Bitmaps instead of BufferedImage. This enables the code to run on Android(which doesn't support AWT). I've also made the effect just manipulate the pixels in a circle rather than the whole Bitmap, this gives a fisheye "lens" effect. Hopes this helps any Android developers.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

class Filters{
    float xscale;
    float yscale;
    float xshift;
    float yshift;
    int [] s;
    private String TAG = "Filters";
    public Filters(){

        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside constructor");
    }

    public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k){
        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside barrel method ");
        float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
        float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;

        int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
        int height = input.getHeight();

        Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,input.getConfig() ); //output pic
        Log.e(TAG, "***********dst bitmap created ");
          xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);
          float newcenterX = width-centerX;
          float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);

          yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);
          float newcenterY = height-centerY;
          float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

          xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
          yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;
          Log.e(TAG, "***********about to loop through bm");
          /*for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                sampleImage(input,x,y);
                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);

              }
            }*/

          int origPixel; // the pixel in orig image

          for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                 origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);
                float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                sampleImage(input,x,y);
                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");


// check whether a pixel is within the circle bounds of 150

                if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= 150 ){
                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);
                }else{
                    dst.setPixel(i,j,origPixel);
                }
              }
            }
        return dst;
    }

    void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
    {
        s = new int [4];
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
        s[0]=0;
        s[1]=0;
        s[2]=0;
        s[3]=0;
        return;
      }

      float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);

      int [] s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      int [] s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

      s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
      s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
      s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
      s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));
    }

    int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){
        int rgb = buf.getPixel(y, x); // Returns by default ARGB.
        int [] scalar = new int[4];
        scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
        scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
        scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
        scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
        return scalar;
    }

    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float thresh = 1;

    float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){
      float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
      float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
      float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

      if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
        return x1;
      if(res3<0){
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
      }
      else{
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
      }
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.util.Log;

public class MultiRuntimeProcessorFilter {



    private static final String TAG = "mrpf";
    private int x = 0;
    private Bitmap input = null;
    private int radius;


    public void createBitmapSections(int nOp, int[] sections){

        int processors = nOp;
        int jMax = input.getHeight();
        int aSectionSize = (int) Math.ceil(jMax/processors);
        Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ sections size = "+aSectionSize);


        int k = 0;
        for(int h=0; h<processors+1; h++){

                sections[h] = k;
                k+= aSectionSize;



        }
    }// end of createBitmapSections()



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k, int r){
          this.radius = r;
          this.input = input;
          int []arr = new int[input.getWidth()*input.getHeight()];


          Log.e(TAG, "bitmap height = "+input.getHeight()); 




          int nrOfProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
          Log.e(TAG, "no of processors = "+nrOfProcessors);

          int[] sections = new int[nrOfProcessors+1];


          createBitmapSections(nrOfProcessors,sections);
          ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrOfProcessors);

          for(int g=0; g<sections.length;g++){
              Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ sections= "+sections[g]);
          }

         // ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrOfProcessors);

          Object[] task = new Object[nrOfProcessors];

          for(int z = 0; z < nrOfProcessors; z++){
             task[z]  = (FutureTask<PartialResult>) threadPool.submit(new PartialProcessing(sections[z], sections[z+1] - 1, input, k));  
             Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ task"+z+"= "+task[z].toString()); 
          }

         PartialResult[] results = new PartialResult[nrOfProcessors];

         try{
              for(int t = 0; t < nrOfProcessors; t++){

                  results[t] = ((FutureTask<PartialResult>) task[t]).get();

                  results[t].fill(arr);
              }

          }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          Bitmap dst2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(arr,input.getWidth(),input.getHeight(),input.getConfig());


        return dst2;


        }//end of barrel()




    public class PartialResult {
           int startP;
           int endP;
           int[] storedValues;

           public PartialResult(int startp, int endp, Bitmap input){

               this.startP = startp;
               this.endP = endp;
               this.storedValues = new int[input.getWidth()*input.getHeight()];


           }

           public void addValue(int p, int result) {
                 storedValues[p] = result;

           }

           public void fill(int[] arr) {



              for (int p = startP; p < endP; p++){
                  for(int b=0;b<radius;b++,x++)
                 arr[x] = storedValues[x];

              } 
              Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ x ="+x);
              }

           }//end of partialResult




    public class PartialProcessing implements Callable<PartialResult> {
        int startJ;
        int endJ;


        private int[] scalar;
        private float xscale;
        private float yscale;
        private float xshift;
        private float yshift;
        private float thresh = 1;
        private int [] s1;
        private int [] s2;
        private int [] s3;
        private int [] s4;
        private int [] s;
        private Bitmap input;
        private float k;



        public PartialProcessing(int startj, int endj, Bitmap input, float k) {

            this.startJ = startj;
            this.endJ = endj;
            this.input = input;
            this.k = k;

            s = new int[4];
            scalar = new int[4];
            s1 = new int[4];
            s2 = new int[4];
            s3 = new int[4];
            s4 = new int[4];

        }

        int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){

            int rgb = buf.getPixel(y, x); // Returns by default ARGB.
            // int [] scalar = new int[4];
           //  scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
             scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
             scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
             scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
             return scalar;

        }



        float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

            x = (x*xscale+xshift);
            y = (y*yscale+yshift);
            float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
            return res;
          }

          float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

            x = (x*xscale+xshift);
            y = (y*yscale+yshift);
            float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
            return res;
          }



          float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){

            float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
            float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
            float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

            if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
              return x1;
            if(res3<0){
              return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
            }
            else{
              return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
            }
          }


          void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
          {

             // s = new int [4];
            if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
              s[0]=0;
              s[1]=0;
              s[2]=0;
              s[3]=0;
              return;
            }

            float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
            float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
            float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
            float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);



             s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
             s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
             s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
             s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

            float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
            float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

           // s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
            s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
            s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
            s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));


          }



        @Override public PartialResult call() { 

             PartialResult partialResult = new PartialResult(startJ, endJ,input);

             float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
             float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;



             int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
             int height = input.getHeight();



              xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);

              float newcenterX = width-centerX;
              float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);

              yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);

              float newcenterY = height-centerY;
              float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

              xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;

              yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;


            int p = startJ*radius; 
            int origPixel = 0;
            int color = 0;
            int i;

            for (int j = startJ; j <  endJ; j++){

                for ( i = 0; i < width; i++, p++){


             origPixel = input.getPixel(i,j);

             float x = getRadialX((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);


             float y = getRadialY((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);

             sampleImage(input,x,y);

             color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
            //Log.e(TAG, "radius = "+radius);

             if(((i-centerX)*(i-centerX) + (j-centerY)*(j-centerY)) <= radius*(radius/4)){

                                 partialResult.addValue(p, color);


            }else{


                partialResult.addValue(p, origPixel);



            }

                }//end of inner for

        }//end of outer for

            return partialResult;
    }//end of call


}// end of partialprocessing

}//end of MultiProcesorFilter
```

@And_Dev as promised

Below is the view that gets the users touch co-ords and then calls the filter on a selected area. the selected area is the cord eg center of circle plus a radius(a circle). the code does this twice as its for a breast augmentation app:) Just comment out the HorizontalSlider code as you don't need this.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.tecmark.HorizontalSlider.OnProgressChangeListener;

public class TouchView extends View{


    private File tempFile;
    private byte[] imageArray;
    private Bitmap bgr;

    private Bitmap crop;
    private Bitmap crop2;
    private Bitmap overLay;
    private Bitmap overLay2;


    private float centreX;
    private float centreY;
    private float centreA = 200;
    private float centreB = 200;
    private Boolean xyFound = false;
    private int Progress = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "*********TouchView";
    private Filters f = null;
    private boolean bothCirclesInPlace = false;
    private MultiProcessorFilter mpf;
    private MultiProcessorFilter mpf2;
    private MultiRuntimeProcessorFilter mrpf;
    private MultiRuntimeProcessorFilter mrpf2;





    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }




    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);
        Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ inside touchview constructor");



        tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                getAbsolutePath() + "/"+"image.jpg");

        imageArray = new byte[(int)tempFile.length()];


     try{

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);


            int i = 0;

            while (dis.available() > 0) {
            imageArray[i] = dis.readByte();
            i++;
            }

            dis.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {

               e.printStackTrace();
            }


       Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length);




        bgr = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);;

        overLay = null;
        overLay2 = null;



       bm.recycle();

    }// end of touchView constructor




    public void findCirclePixels(){ 

         //  f = new Filters();
         //  mpf = new MultiProcessorFilter();
         //  mpf2 = new MultiProcessorFilter();
         mrpf = new MultiRuntimeProcessorFilter();
         mrpf2 = new MultiRuntimeProcessorFilter();

         crop = Bitmap.createBitmap(bgr,Math.max((int)centreX-75,0),Math.max((int)centreY-75,0),150,150);
         crop2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bgr,Math.max((int)centreA-75,0),Math.max((int)centreB-75,0),150,150);

              new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    float prog = (float)Progress/150001;

               // final Bitmap bgr3 = f.barrel(crop,prog);
               // final Bitmap bgr4 = f.barrel(crop2,prog);

              //  final Bitmap bgr3 = mpf.barrel(crop,prog);
              //  final Bitmap bgr4 = mpf2.barrel(crop2,prog);

                    final Bitmap bgr3 = mrpf.barrel(crop,prog);
                    final Bitmap bgr4 = mrpf2.barrel(crop2,prog);

                  TouchView.this.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                      TouchView.this.overLay = bgr3;
                      TouchView.this.overLay2 = bgr4;

                      TouchView.this.invalidate();

                    }
                  });
                }
              }).start();


        }// end of changePixel()






    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                if(xyFound == false){
                centreX = (int) ev.getX();
                centreY = (int) ev.getY();
                xyFound = true;
                }else{
                centreA = (int) ev.getX();
                centreB = (int) ev.getY();
                bothCirclesInPlace  = true;
                }


                break;
            }

          /*  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                if(xyFound == false){
                    centreX = (int) ev.getX();
                    centreY = (int) ev.getY();
                    xyFound = true;
                }else{
                    centreA = (int) ev.getX();
                    centreB = (int) ev.getY();
                    bothCirclesInPlace = true;
                    }

                    findCirclePixels();
                 // TouchView.this.invalidate();
                    break;

            }*/           

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 

                break;

        }
        return true;
    }//end of onTouchEvent





    public void initSlider(final HorizontalSlider slider)
    {

        slider.setOnProgressChangeListener(changeListener);


    }



    private OnProgressChangeListener changeListener = new OnProgressChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(View v, int progress) {



              setProgress(progress);



        }
    };




    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Log.e(TAG, "******about to draw bgr ");
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);

        if(bothCirclesInPlace == true){

                if(overLay != null){
                    Log.e(TAG, "******about to draw overlay1 ");
        canvas.drawBitmap(overLay, centreX-75, centreY-75, null);
                }
            if(overLay2 != null){
                Log.e(TAG, "******about to draw overlay2 ");
        canvas.drawBitmap(overLay2, centreA-75, centreB-75, null);
            }

        }

    }//end of onDraw




    protected void setProgress(int progress2) {
        Log.e(TAG, "***********in SETPROGRESS");
        this.Progress = progress2;



        findCirclePixels();


    }




}
```

.

The calling activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Jjilapp extends Activity {




    private static final String TAG = "*********jjil";


    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.touchview);
        final TouchView touchView = (TouchView)findViewById(R.id.touchview); 
        final HorizontalSlider slider = (HorizontalSlider)findViewById(R.id.slider); 

        touchView.initSlider(slider);




    }//end of oncreate




}
```

If you need any help mate just ask. hope this helps

Comment: I have tried your code in android but the sphere is still black. I have also tried this on OpenCV and its working fine but i need this feature in android app. Could you please guide me on this. 
Thanks

Comment: @Challenger what version of android are you running it on?

Comment: I have debugged it and found the problem that alpha value of pixel is not setting up in the sphere region that why it coming black. setting the alpha of pixel solves the problem. Thanks for your time

Comment: @challenger hey glad you worked it out! I've actually re-done this code so it processes the bitmap using parallelisation. It check the device to see how many processor are available eg on my htc one X there are 4 cores. it will divide the bitmap into 4, assign each core a segment and then stitch it all back together when done. You can have the code if you like, just let me know. it works on android 2.1, but not too good on android 4.0. if u wanna play around with it and see if u can get it going, if u do, i just ask for an update;)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate for your help. I have used the above code it's working great for square image but when image has too much difference between width and height then output sphere will come black from the boundary also its not from the centre, I have tried to debugged but not successful yet, if you any idea how to resolve this issue please share it. It would be my pleasure if you share the parallisation code with me.

Comment: @Challenger Hi i've updated the post to include the parallelisation code. It works on samsung galaxy portal running android 2.1 but not on my htc oneX running android 4.0. if you can get it going before me will you update me please, thanks.

Comment: Hey @turtleboy thanks, It nice to see ur answer help me to some extent. I have a question, I am creating an app, which like lensOut some area in image, like Eyes . Do you know any clue on this.? if your code will work on this situation.

Comment: @AND_DEV hi, this code create a barrel lens/fish-eye distortion. the app i did was for a breast augmentation app. you pass a bitmap in and it creates the effect of larger breasts. so maybe it is what you want. it seems like the bitmap is bulging out. imagine a table cloth on a table with 2 balls underneath. the cloth is like the bitmap. best way i can describe it. let me know if you want more code:)

Comment: Thanks for response, I got that from ur earlier responses, u are pretty clear in writing, And I am quite understood with Breast example u have given ;)>

even I am doing same kinda thing, need to pop out Eyes, and pop in mouth.

i tried this but it is creating white circle in center, I want something where I touch or where i can give point. if I can have ur Email ID it will be great so can share things over there

Comment: hi, no probs, i can do anything at moment as i've not got source code with me. i'll have a look at stuff later tonight or tomorrow and get in touch with you. I have the code where you touch the screen and it places the distortion at that point. bear with me and i'll give you the code.

Comment: i can't do anything at mo, i meant :)

Comment: @AND_DEV Hi, Sorry it's taken so long but i've been a bit busy. if you need any help it's cool just message me.

Comment: Yes this is not working for me. Will mail you the code I am using.

Comment: @AND_DEV before you do anything, which version of android are you using. When i wrote the code it was for Android 2.1 It works on a phone running this but not on my newer phone running 4+. If you can test it on 2.1 first to see if it works, then you may have to sort out the bug in android 4+.

Comment: that is good.. i was trying it on Emulator with 2.3 version, and HTC phone with 4.0 Version.

Comment: @AND_DEV I've only tested it on 2 phones that is a Samsung galaxy portal 2.1. it worked on that. The other phone that it didn't work on was HTC One X running 4.0. If you get it running on the higher level android will you let me know what the problem is. thanks Matt

Comment: surely I will do that, But I am afraid if it will work for me on lower version first.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to you for that code. It helps me a lot. I  transcrypted it for Java. Maybe someone has a similar function for symulating tangencial distorsion?

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.jhlabs.image.InterpolateFilter;

class Filters{
    float xscale;
    float yscale;
    float xshift;
    float yshift;
    int [] s;
    public Filters(){

    }

    public BufferedImage barrel (BufferedImage input, float k){

        float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
        float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;

        int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
        int height = input.getHeight();

        BufferedImage dst = new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); //output pic

          xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);
          float newcenterX = width-centerX;
          float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);

          yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);
          float newcenterY = height-centerY;
          float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

          xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
          yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;

          for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                sampleImage(input,x,y);
                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                dst.setRGB(i, j, color);

              }
            }
        return dst;
    }

    void sampleImage(BufferedImage arr, float idx0, float idx1)
    {
        s = new int [4];
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
        s[0]=0;
        s[1]=0;
        s[2]=0;
        s[3]=0;
        return;
      }

      float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);

      int [] s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      int [] s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

      s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
      s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
      s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
      s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));
    }

    int [] getARGB(BufferedImage buf,int x, int y){
        int rgb = buf.getRGB(x, y); // Returns by default ARGB.
        int [] scalar = new int[4];
        scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
        scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
        scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
        scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
        return scalar;
    }

    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float thresh = 1;

    float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){
      float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
      float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
      float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

      if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
        return x1;
      if(res3<0){
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
      }
      else{
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, this java code is exactly what i need. i'm trying to create the same efect on Android but can't use bufferedimage, as android doesn't support it. is there a way around to get this code running on android? any help would be appreciated, thanks matt

Answer (score 2):

I debugged the java files and it works fine on my phones(higher than 4.0). It consists of 3 java files and 1 xml file. You have to place checkerboardback.jpg file under drawaable directory. As someone said, alpha value was missing and I gave it "0x0ff". In addition, upperbound of some Looping were wrong.

//1. MultiRuntimeProcessorFilter.java

```
public class MultiRuntimeProcessorFilter {



private static final String TAG = "mrpf";
private int x = 0;
private Bitmap input = null;
private int radius;
private int mHeight;


public void createBitmapSections(int nOp, int[] sections){

    int processors = nOp;
    int jMax = input.getHeight();
    int aSectionSize = (int) Math.ceil(jMax/processors);
    Log.e("yoSIZECHK", "++++++++++ sections size = "+aSectionSize);

    int k = 0;
    for(int h=0; h<processors+1; h++){

            sections[h] = k;
            k+= aSectionSize;
            if(h==processors){
                sections[h] = mHeight;//Last must cover ceiling
            }
        Log.v("yoSEC","sections = "+h+" "+sections[h]);

    }
}// end of createBitmapSections()


//@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k, int r){
      this.radius = r;
      this.input = input;
      int []mArray = new int[input.getWidth()*input.getHeight()];

      mHeight = input.getHeight();
      Log.e(TAG, "bitmap height x width = "+mHeight+" "+input.getWidth());
  //Log.v("yoRESULT", "height width = "+ input.getWidth()+" "+input.getHeight());




      int nrOfProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
      Log.e(TAG, "no of processors = "+nrOfProcessors);


      int[] sections = new int[nrOfProcessors+1];


      createBitmapSections(nrOfProcessors,sections);
      ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrOfProcessors);

      for(int g=0; g<sections.length;g++){
          Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ sections= "+sections[g]);
      }

  // ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrOfProcessors);

      Object[] task = new Object[nrOfProcessors];

      for(int z = 0; z < nrOfProcessors; z++){
         task[z]  = (FutureTask<PartialResult>) threadPool.submit(new PartialProcessing(sections[z], sections[z+1] - 1, input, k, z));
         Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ task"+z+"= "+task[z].toString()); 
      }

     PartialResult[] results = new PartialResult[nrOfProcessors];

     try{
          for(int t = 0; t < nrOfProcessors; t++){

              results[t] = ((FutureTask<PartialResult>) task[t]).get();

              results[t].fill(mArray);
          }

      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

 Log.v("yoRESULT", "height width = "+ input.getHeight()+" "+input.getWidth());
      Bitmap dst2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(mArray,input.getWidth(),input.getHeight(),input.getConfig());

    return dst2;


    }//end of barrel()




public class PartialResult {
       int startP;
       int endP;
       int[] storedValues;

       public PartialResult(int startp, int endp, Bitmap input){

           this.startP = startp;
           this.endP = endp;
           this.storedValues = new int[input.getWidth()*input.getHeight()];


       }

       public void addValue(int p, int result) {
             storedValues[p] = result;

       }

       public void fill(int[] mArray) {

           Log.v("yo09", startP + " " + endP + " " + input.getWidth());
           //yoko for (int p = startP; p < endP; p++){
       for (int p = startP; p < endP+1; p++){
               //for(int b=0;b<radius;b++,x++)
              for(int b=0;b<input.getWidth();b++,x++) {
                  mArray[x] = storedValues[x];
                  if (b == 0) Log.v("yoyoyo", p+" + " + storedValues[x]);
              }
          } 
          Log.e("yoFill", " ++++++++++ radius x = "+radius+" "+x);
   }

       }//end of partialResult




public class PartialProcessing implements Callable<PartialResult> {
    int startJ;
    int endJ;
    int mID;


    private int[] scalar;
    private float xscale;
    private float yscale;
    private float xshift;
    private float yshift;
    private float thresh = 1;
    private int [] s1;
    private int [] s2;
    private int [] s3;
    private int [] s4;
    private int [] s;
    private Bitmap input;
    private float k;



    public PartialProcessing(int startj, int endj, Bitmap input, float k, int mID) {

        this.startJ = startj;
        this.endJ = endj;
        this.input = input;
        this.k = k;
        this.mID = mID;

        s = new int[4];
        scalar = new int[4];
        s1 = new int[4];
        s2 = new int[4];
        s3 = new int[4];
        s4 = new int[4];

    }

    int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){

        int rgb = buf.getPixel(y, x); // Returns by default ARGB.
        // int [] scalar = new int[4];
       //  scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
         scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
         scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
         scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
         return scalar;

    }



    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

        x = (x*xscale+xshift);
        y = (y*yscale+yshift);
        float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
        return res;
      }

      float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

        x = (x*xscale+xshift);
        y = (y*yscale+yshift);
        float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
        return res;
      }



      float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){

        float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
        float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
        float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

        if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
          return x1;
        if(res3<0){
          return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
        }
        else{
          return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
        }
      }


      //void sampleImage(Bitmap mArray, float idx0, float idx1)
    int [] sampleImage(Bitmap mArray2, float idx0, float idx1)
      {

         // s = new int [4];
        if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(mArray2.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(mArray2.getWidth()-1)){
          s[0]=0;
          s[1]=0;
          s[2]=0;
          s[3]=0;
          return s;// yoko
        }

        float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
        float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
        float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
        float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);



    s1 = getARGB(mArray2,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
    s2 = getARGB(mArray2,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
    s3 = getARGB(mArray2,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
    s4 = getARGB(mArray2,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

        float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
        float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

       // s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
        s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
        s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
        s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));

          return s;

      }



    @Override
    public PartialResult call() {

         PartialResult partialResult = new PartialResult(startJ, endJ,input);

         float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
         float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;



         int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
         int height = input.getHeight();



          xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);

          float newcenterX = width-centerX;
          float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);

          yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);

          float newcenterY = height-centerY;
          float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

          xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;

          yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;


        // yoko int p = startJ*radius;
        int p = startJ*width;//yoko
        int origPixel = 0;
        int color = 0;
        int i;

    Log.v("yokoIJ","PartialResult startJ endJ "+startJ+"  "+endJ);
        //yoko for (int j = startJ; j <  endJ; j++){
        for (int j = startJ; j <  endJ+1; j++){
            for ( i = 0; i < width; i++, p++){
    s = new int [4];//yoko added

    origPixel = input.getPixel(i,j);

    float x = getRadialX((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);
    float y = getRadialY((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);
    //sampleImage(input,x,y); //yoko
    s= sampleImage(input,x,y);

    color = (0xff<<24)|((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //Log.e(TAG, "radius = "+radius);

     //Not understand why it is not radius but radius/2
         //yoko if(((i-centerX)*(i-centerX) + (j-centerY)*(j-centerY)) <= radius*(radius/4)){
    if(((i-centerX)*(i-centerX) + (j-centerY)*(j-centerY)) <= radius*radius){
                //yo if(j%10 == 1 && i%10 == 1)
                    //yo Log.v("yoJI", mID+" "+j + " " + i );
        partialResult.addValue(p, color);
    }else{
        partialResult.addValue(p, origPixel);
        }

            }//end of inner for

    }//end of outer for

        return partialResult;
}//end of call
}// end of partialprocessing
}//end of MultiProcesorFilter
```

---

//    2. Filters.java:

```
class Filters{
float xscale;
float yscale;
float xshift;
float yshift;
int [] s;
private static String TAG = "Filters";
public Filters(){
    Log.e(TAG, "***********inside constructor");
}

public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k, boolean check, int Range){
    Log.e(TAG, "***********inside barrel method : hasAlpha = ");
    float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
    float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;

    int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
    int height = input.getHeight();

//yoko        Log.v("yoQQ", width+" "+height+" "+centerX+" "+centerY);
    if(check)return input;

    Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,input.getConfig() ); //output pic
    Log.e(TAG, "***********dst bitmap created ");
      xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);
      float newcenterX = width-centerX;

    float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);
      yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);
      float newcenterY = height-centerY;
      float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

      xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
      yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;
      Log.e(TAG, "***********about to loop through bm");
  Log.v("yoQQ2", xscale + " " + yscale);
  //if(check==1)return input;//yoko
      /*for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
          for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
            float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
            float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
            sampleImage(input,x,y);
            int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
//            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

            dst.setPixel(i, j, color);

          }
        }*/

      int origPixel; // the pixel in orig image
      int i=0,j=0;
      for(j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
          for(i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
            s = new int [4];//yoko added
             origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);
            float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
            float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
            //yoko sampleImage(input,x,y);
            s = sampleImage(input,x,y);
            //yoko int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
            int color = (0xff<<24)|((s[1]&0xff)<<16)|((s[2]&0xff)<<8)|(s[3]&0xff);
            //Log.v("yoQQ3", j + " " + i + " : "+dst.getHeight()+" "+dst.getWidth());


    // check whether a pixel is within the circle bounds of 150

            if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= Range ){
        dst.setPixel(i, j, color);
                //if(j%10 == 1 && i%10 == 1)
                //    Log.v("yoJI", j + " " + i );
            }else{
                dst.setPixel(i,j,origPixel);
            }
          }
        }
    Log.v("yoDONE", "========  Loop End ======== "+j+" "+i+" : " + dst.getHeight()+" "+dst.getWidth());
    return dst;
}//barrel

//    void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1) // yoko
int[] sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
{
    s = new int [4];
  if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
    s[0]=0;
    s[1]=0;
    s[2]=0;
    s[3]=0;
    return s;
  }

  float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
  float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
  float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
  float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);

  int [] s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
  int [] s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
  int [] s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
  int [] s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

  float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
  float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

  s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
  s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
  s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
  s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));
  return s;///yoko added to make return the result value
}//sampleImage

int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){
    int rgb = buf.getPixel(y, x); // Returns by default ARGB.
    int [] scalar = new int[4];
    scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
    scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
    scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
    scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
    return scalar;
}//getARGB

float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
  x = (x*xscale+xshift);
  y = (y*yscale+yshift);
  float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
  return res;
}//getRadial1X

float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
  x = (x*xscale+xshift);
  y = (y*yscale+yshift);
  float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
  return res;
}//getRadialY

float thresh = 1;

float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){
  float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
  float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
  float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

  if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
    return x1;
  if(res3<0){
    return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
  }
  else{
    return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
  }
}//calc_shift
}
```

And 
//3 MainActivity.java, toplevel class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView iv1=null;
ImageView iv2=null;
Button bT, bB, b0;
Bitmap bitmap1, bitmap2, bitmapSP;
Boolean view1 = true;
private static final String TAG = "*********jjil";
public static int mH,mW,RADIUS;

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = this.getResources();
    //bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.checkerboard);
    bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.checkerboardback);
    mH=bitmap1.getHeight();
    mW=bitmap1.getWidth();
    RADIUS = mH/3;

    bT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontoggle);
    bT.setOnClickListener(onClickToggleView);
    bB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonbarrel);
    bB.setOnClickListener(onClickToggleView);
    b0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
    b0.setOnClickListener(onClickToggleView);

    iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.touchview1);
    iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
    iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}//end of oncreate

public View.OnClickListener onClickToggleView = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == bT) {

    /// fromhere
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                com.example.owner.opengl2.Filters mFilers = new com.example.owner.opengl2.Filters();
                TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mStatus);
                Bitmap bitmapSP;long start,end;

                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    start = System.nanoTime();
                    iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                    tx.setText("- Running -");
                }

                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                     bitmapSP = mFilers.barrel(bitmap1,(float)0.00005,false,RADIUS);
                    return "message";
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                    end = System.nanoTime();
                    long elapsedTime = end - start;
                    long seconds = elapsedTime / 1000000;

                    iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmapSP);
                    tx.setText("- READY : ElapsedTime(ms) = "+seconds);
                    // Post Code
                    // Use `msg` in code
                }
            }.execute();
    ///upto here



        } else if (v == bB){

    /// fromhere
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                com.example.owner.opengl2.MultiRuntimeProcessorFilter mFilers = new com.example.owner.opengl2.MultiRuntimeProcessorFilter();
                TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mStatus);
                Bitmap bitmapSP;long start,end;

                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    start = System.nanoTime();
                    iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                    tx.setText("- Running -");
                }

                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    bitmapSP = mFilers.barrel(bitmap1,(float)0.00005,RADIUS);
                    return "message";
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                    end = System.nanoTime();
                    long elapsedTime = end - start;
                    //double seconds = (double)elapsedTime / 1000000000.0;
                    long seconds = elapsedTime / 1000000;
                    iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmapSP);
                    tx.setText("- READY : ElapsedTime(ms) = "+seconds);
                    // Post Code
                    // Use `msg` in code
                }
            }.execute();


        } else if (v == b0){
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                protected String doInBackground(Void... Unused) {
                    return "OK";
                }
                protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
                    Log.v("YO", "---------------------------------");
                    Log.v("YO", "----------ORIGINAL SHAPE-------- "+message);
                    Log.v("YO", "---------------------------------");
                    iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

                    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mStatus);
                    tx.setText("- READY : w h RADIUS = "+mW+" "+mH+" "+RADIUS);
                }
            }.execute();

        }
        ///upto here

    }
};
```

}

Here is XML file
//4 activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttontoggle"
        android:text="Barrel 1P"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonbarrel"
    android:text="Barrele NP"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:text="ORIGINAL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" - Ready - "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/touchview1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mStatus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />

<!--ImageView
    android:id="@+id/touchview2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/touchview1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use this distortion on sintetic images, or do you want to apply to a video camera or something ?

In OpenCv you should be able to do camera calibration (using the built-in functions, Zhang's algorithm) ..

In [OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919917/how-to-create-fisheye-lens-effect-by-opengl) see this.

Regards