# BufferedImage in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, bufferedimage

I've an app that takes a camera picture and saves on sdcard as jpeg. i want to distort the picture with a spherize filter. I can read the jpeg to a bitmap, but the code i have found that does the distortion distorts a bufferedimage. i understand that javax.imageio is not supported in android but is there a way of reading a jpeg into the memory as a bufferedimage?

thanks mat.

```
/*
Copyright 2006 Jerry Huxtable

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

package com.jhlabs.image;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

/**
 * A filter which simulates a lens placed over an image.
 */
public class SphereFilter extends TransformFilter {

    private float a = 0;
    private float b = 0;
    private float a2 = 0;
    private float b2 = 0;
    private float centreX = 0.5f;
    private float centreY = 0.5f;
    private float refractionIndex = 1.5f;

    private float icentreX;
    private float icentreY;

    public SphereFilter() {
        setEdgeAction( CLAMP );
        setRadius( 100.0f );
    }

    /**
     * Set the index of refaction.
     * @param refractionIndex the index of refaction
     * @see #getRefractionIndex
     */
    public void setRefractionIndex(float refractionIndex) {
        this.refractionIndex = refractionIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Get the index of refaction.
     * @return the index of refaction
     * @see #setRefractionIndex
     */
    public float getRefractionIndex() {
        return refractionIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Set the radius of the effect.
     * @param r the radius
     * @min-value 0
     * @see #getRadius
     */
    public void setRadius(float r) {
        this.a = r;
        this.b = r;
    }

    /**
     * Get the radius of the effect.
     * @return the radius
     * @see #setRadius
     */
    public float getRadius() {
        return a;
    }

    /**
     * Set the centre of the effect in the X direction as a proportion of the image size.
     * @param centreX the center
     * @see #getCentreX
     */
    public void setCentreX( float centreX ) {
        this.centreX = centreX;
    }

    public float getCentreX() {
        return centreX;
    }

    /**
     * Set the centre of the effect in the Y direction as a proportion of the image size.
     * @param centreY the center
     * @see #getCentreY
     */
    public void setCentreY( float centreY ) {
        this.centreY = centreY;
    }

    /**
     * Get the centre of the effect in the Y direction as a proportion of the image size.
     * @return the center
     * @see #setCentreY
     */
    public float getCentreY() {
        return centreY;
    }

    /**
     * Set the centre of the effect as a proportion of the image size.
     * @param centre the center
     * @see #getCentre
     */
    public void setCentre( Point2D centre ) {
        this.centreX = (float)centre.getX();
        this.centreY = (float)centre.getY();
    }

    /**
     * Get the centre of the effect as a proportion of the image size.
     * @return the center
     * @see #setCentre
     */
    public Point2D getCentre() {
        return new Point2D.Float( centreX, centreY );
    }

    public BufferedImage filter( BufferedImage src, BufferedImage dst ) {
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        icentreX = width * centreX;
        icentreY = height * centreY;
        if (a == 0)
            a = width/2;
        if (b == 0)
            b = height/2;
        a2 = a*a;
        b2 = b*b;
        return super.filter( src, dst );
    }

    protected void transformInverse(int x, int y, float[] out) {
        float dx = x-icentreX;
        float dy = y-icentreY;
        float x2 = dx*dx;
        float y2 = dy*dy;
        if (y2 >= (b2 - (b2*x2)/a2)) {
            out[0] = x;
            out[1] = y;
        } else {
            float rRefraction = 1.0f / refractionIndex;

            float z = (float)Math.sqrt((1.0f - x2/a2 - y2/b2) * (a*b));
            float z2 = z*z;

            float xAngle = (float)Math.acos(dx / Math.sqrt(x2+z2));
            float angle1 = ImageMath.HALF_PI - xAngle;
            float angle2 = (float)Math.asin(Math.sin(angle1)*rRefraction);
            angle2 = ImageMath.HALF_PI - xAngle - angle2;
            out[0] = x - (float)Math.tan(angle2)*z;

            float yAngle = (float)Math.acos(dy / Math.sqrt(y2+z2));
            angle1 = ImageMath.HALF_PI - yAngle;
            angle2 = (float)Math.asin(Math.sin(angle1)*rRefraction);
            angle2 = ImageMath.HALF_PI - yAngle - angle2;
            out[1] = y - (float)Math.tan(angle2)*z;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Distort/Sphere...";
    }

}
```

Comment: If you share the code it would be easier to help.

Comment: @dirhem here's the spherize code, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. You can't use `BufferedImage` because, like you said, `javax.imageio` isn't in the Android SDK. The `Bitmap` class, however, does support getting individual pixels using the [`getPixel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29) and [`getPixels()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) methods so you should be able to use those to do any type of image transform you want to do.

Comment: pond hi, could i ask you how you would start to go about using these methods to alter the pixels in a bitmap. Are there any good links you can give me that talk me through it. i'm new to android and haven't a clue about image processing. i'd like to know how to rearrange the pixels in my bitmap so i can make some simple effects to start with then try to implement the fisheye effect later

Comment: @ pond thanks for that advice! You can indeed use the get/setPixel() methods to do the required transforms on Bitmaps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927145/how-to-simulate-fisheye-lens-effect-by-opencv

Answer (score 0):

BufferedImage is part of AWT, which is not implemented in Java.  You need to find Android replacements for what you're trying to do.

Read this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitmap instead of bufferedimage but this won't resolve your problem since you need make changes on TransformFilter because this code eventually call the `super.filter( src, dst );` which is making the actual job. If your only goal is to implement spherize filter, [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/displacementfilters.aspx) provides a direct algorithm for spherize filter which would be easier to port to Android.

Comment: Hi, i'm still at a loss at getting a fisheye effect. When you say "port to Android", could you explain briefly how to do this? sorry i'm new to Android and using libraries written in different languages with java seems a little daunting.