# Android bitmap to bufferedimage

Tags: java, android, bitmap, image-manipulation

Is there a simple way to convert a Bitmap image datatype to a BufferedImage?

I need a bitmap image scaled to 224*224 to be converted into a BufferedImage in order to do pixel comparisons between two BufferedImages.

I've been trying to develop a simple facial recognition class that would take 2 bitmap images (taken from the android camera) and compare them using a local binary pattern recognition algorithm. source code for image comparison:

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;

public class ImageEncode {

 public static boolean facialRecognition(BufferedImage i, BufferedImage i2) {

  int currentPixelValue, newPixelValue;
  int[][] imageArray = new int[224][224], imageArray2 = new int[224][224], lbpArray = new int[224][224], lbpArray2 = new int[224][224], histogram = new int[9][256], histogram2 = new int[9][256];



  //input pictures, resize to 224x224
  BufferedImage image = i;
  BufferedImage image2 = i2;

  //convert to gray scale
  ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
  ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(cs, null);
  image = op.filter(image, null);
  image2=op.filter(image2, null);

  //gaussian filter
  Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3,3,
    new float[] {
     1f/9f, 1f/9f, 1f/9f,
     1f/9f, 1f/9f, 1f/9f,
     1f/9f, 1f/9f, 1f/9f});
  BufferedImageOp op2 = new ConvolveOp(kernel);
  image = op2.filter(image, null);
  image2= op2.filter(image2, null);

  //convert images to pixel value array
  for(int row=0; row<=223; row++){
   for(int col=0; col<=223; col++){
    imageArray[row][col]=image.getRGB(row, col);
    imageArray2[row][col]=image2.getRGB(row, col);
   }
  }  

  //perform lbp calculations  
  for(int row=1; row<223; row++){
   for(int col=1; col<223; col++){
    currentPixelValue=imageArray[row][col];
    newPixelValue=0;
    if(imageArray[row-1][col-1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+1;
    if(imageArray[row-1][col]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+2;
    if(imageArray[row-1][col+1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+4;
    if(imageArray[row][col+1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+8;
    if(imageArray[row+1][col+1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+16;
    if(imageArray[row+1][col]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+32;
    if(imageArray[row+1][col-1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+64;
    if(imageArray[row][col-1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+128;
    lbpArray[row][col]=newPixelValue;
   }
  }

  for(int row=1; row<223; row++){
   for(int col=1; col<223; col++){
    currentPixelValue=imageArray2[row][col];
    newPixelValue=0;
    if(imageArray2[row-1][col-1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+1;
    if(imageArray2[row-1][col]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+2;
    if(imageArray2[row-1][col+1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+4;
    if(imageArray2[row][col+1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+8;
    if(imageArray2[row+1][col+1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+16;
    if(imageArray2[row+1][col]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+32;
    if(imageArray2[row+1][col-1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+64;
    if(imageArray2[row][col-1]>currentPixelValue) newPixelValue=newPixelValue+128;
    lbpArray2[row][col]=newPixelValue;
   }
  }

  //create histograms
  for(int row=1; row<=222; row++){
   for(int col=1; col<=222; col++){
    if(row<75 && col<75) histogram[0][imageArray[row][col]]++;
    if(row<75 && col>74 && col<149) histogram[1][imageArray[row][col]]++;
    if(row<75 && col>148 && col<223) histogram[2][imageArray[row][col]]++;
    if(row>74 && row<149 && col<75) histogram[3][imageArray[row][col]]++;
    if(row>74 && row<149 && col>75 && col<149) histogram[4][imageArray[row][col]]++;
    if(row>74 && row<149 && col>148 && col<223) histogram[5][imageArray[row][col]]++;
    if(row>148 && row<223 && col<75) histogram[6][imageArray[row][col]]++;
    if(row>148 && row<223 && col>74 && col<149) histogram[7][imageArray[row][col]]++;
    if(row>148 && row<223 && col>148 && col<223) histogram[8][imageArray[row][col]]++;
   }
  }  

  for(int row=1; row<=222; row++){
   for(int col=1; col<=222; col++){
    if(row<75 && col<75) histogram2[0][imageArray2[row][col]]++;
    if(row<75 && col>74 && col<149) histogram2[1][imageArray2[row][col]]++;
    if(row<75 && col>148 && col<223) histogram2[2][imageArray2[row][col]]++;
    if(row>74 && row<149 && col<75) histogram2[3][imageArray2[row][col]]++;
    if(row>74 && row<149 && col>75 && col<149) histogram2[4][imageArray2[row][col]]++;
    if(row>74 && row<149 && col>148 && col<223) histogram2[5][imageArray2[row][col]]++;
    if(row>148 && row<223 && col<75) histogram2[6][imageArray2[row][col]]++;
    if(row>148 && row<223 && col>74 && col<149) histogram2[7][imageArray2[row][col]]++;
    if(row>148 && row<223 && col>148 && col<223) histogram2[8][imageArray2[row][col]]++;
   }
  }  

  //Compare histograms
  for(int k=0; k<=8; k++){
   for(int j=0; j<=255; j++){
    if((((histogram[k][j])*0.1)+histogram[k][j]) < histogram2[k][j] || (histogram[k][j]-((histogram[k][j])*0.1)) > histogram2[k][j]){
     return false;
    }
   }
  }

  return true;

 }

}
```

Comment: Since BufferedImage isn't available in Android, can you give some more detail about how you are going about doing this?  For example, what kind of things have you tried already, or even some sample code from your project showing what the problem is?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what pixel comparisons you need to do that cannot be done with the `Bitmap` object?  Methods like `getPixel()` and `getPixels()` allow you to return the color data at any given position...

Comment: Wondering is this tagged wrong maybe the tag should be Java not Android since BuferedImage is mentioned.

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a bridge between Android's Bitmap class and java.awt's BufferedImage class, which for us Java folks would be a nice discussion...

Comment: Well if this is a discussion it doesn't belong here as that violates posting policies.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this class many times to convert diferent bitmaps to bufferedimages

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Utility class for loading windows bitmap files
 * <p>
 * Based on code from author Abdul Bezrati and Pepijn Van Eeckhoudt
 */
public class BitmapLoader {

    /**
     * Static method to load a bitmap file based on the filename passed in.
     * Based on the bit count, this method will either call the 8 or 24 bit
     * bitmap reader methods
     *
     * @param file The name of the bitmap file to read
     * @throws IOException
     * @return A BufferedImage of the bitmap
     */
    public static BufferedImage loadBitmap(String file) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image;
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = ResourceRetriever.getResourceAsStream(file);

            int bitmapFileHeaderLength = 14;
            int bitmapInfoHeaderLength = 40;

            byte bitmapFileHeader[] = new byte[bitmapFileHeaderLength];
            byte bitmapInfoHeader[] = new byte[bitmapInfoHeaderLength];

            input.read(bitmapFileHeader, 0, bitmapFileHeaderLength);
            input.read(bitmapInfoHeader, 0, bitmapInfoHeaderLength);

            int nSize = bytesToInt(bitmapFileHeader, 2);
            int nWidth = bytesToInt(bitmapInfoHeader, 4);
            int nHeight = bytesToInt(bitmapInfoHeader, 8);
            int nBiSize = bytesToInt(bitmapInfoHeader, 0);
            int nPlanes = bytesToShort(bitmapInfoHeader, 12);
            int nBitCount = bytesToShort(bitmapInfoHeader, 14);
            int nSizeImage = bytesToInt(bitmapInfoHeader, 20);
            int nCompression = bytesToInt(bitmapInfoHeader, 16);
            int nColoursUsed = bytesToInt(bitmapInfoHeader, 32);
            int nXPixelsMeter = bytesToInt(bitmapInfoHeader, 24);
            int nYPixelsMeter = bytesToInt(bitmapInfoHeader, 28);
            int nImportantColours = bytesToInt(bitmapInfoHeader, 36);

            if (nBitCount == 24) {
                image = read24BitBitmap(nSizeImage, nHeight, nWidth, input);
            } else if (nBitCount == 8) {
                image = read8BitBitmap(nColoursUsed, nBitCount, nSizeImage, nWidth, nHeight, input);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a 24-bit or 8-bit Windows Bitmap, aborting...");
                image = null;
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        return image;
    }

    /**
     * Static method to read a 8 bit bitmap
     *
     * @param nColoursUsed Number of colors used
     * @param nBitCount The bit count
     * @param nSizeImage The size of the image in bytes
     * @param nWidth The width of the image
     * @param input The input stream corresponding to the image
     * @throws IOException
     * @return A BufferedImage of the bitmap
     */
    private static BufferedImage read8BitBitmap(int nColoursUsed, int nBitCount, int nSizeImage, int nWidth, int nHeight, InputStream input) throws IOException {
        int nNumColors = (nColoursUsed > 0) ? nColoursUsed : (1 & 0xff) << nBitCount;

        if (nSizeImage == 0) {
            nSizeImage = ((((nWidth * nBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3);
            nSizeImage *= nHeight;
        }

        int npalette[] = new int[nNumColors];
        byte bpalette[] = new byte[nNumColors * 4];
        readBuffer(input, bpalette);
        int nindex8 = 0;

        for (int n = 0; n < nNumColors; n++) {
            npalette[n] = (255 & 0xff) << 24 |
                    (bpalette[nindex8 + 2] & 0xff) << 16 |
                    (bpalette[nindex8 + 1] & 0xff) << 8 |
                    (bpalette[nindex8 + 0] & 0xff);

            nindex8 += 4;
        }

        int npad8 = (nSizeImage / nHeight) - nWidth;
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(nWidth, nHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        DataBufferInt dataBufferByte = ((DataBufferInt) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer());
        int[][] bankData = dataBufferByte.getBankData();
        byte bdata[] = new byte[(nWidth + npad8) * nHeight];

        readBuffer(input, bdata);
        nindex8 = 0;

        for (int j8 = nHeight - 1; j8 >= 0; j8--) {
            for (int i8 = 0; i8 < nWidth; i8++) {
                bankData[0][j8 * nWidth + i8] = npalette[((int) bdata[nindex8] & 0xff)];
                nindex8++;
            }
            nindex8 += npad8;
        }

        return bufferedImage;
    }

    /**
     * Static method to read a 24 bit bitmap
     *
     * @param nSizeImage size of the image  in bytes
     * @param nHeight The height of the image
     * @param nWidth The width of the image
     * @param input The input stream corresponding to the image
     * @throws IOException
     * @return A BufferedImage of the bitmap
     */
    private static BufferedImage read24BitBitmap(int nSizeImage, int nHeight, int nWidth, InputStream input) throws IOException {
        int npad = (nSizeImage / nHeight) - nWidth * 3;
        if (npad == 4 || npad < 0)
            npad = 0;
        int nindex = 0;
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(nWidth, nHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        DataBufferByte dataBufferByte = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer());
        byte[][] bankData = dataBufferByte.getBankData();
        byte brgb[] = new byte[(nWidth + npad) * 3 * nHeight];

        readBuffer(input, brgb);

        for (int j = nHeight - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nWidth; i++) {
                int base = (j * nWidth + i) * 4;
                bankData[0][base] = (byte) 255;
                bankData[0][base + 1] = brgb[nindex];
                bankData[0][base + 2] = brgb[nindex + 1];
                bankData[0][base + 3] = brgb[nindex + 2];
                nindex += 3;
            }
            nindex += npad;
        }

        return bufferedImage;
    }

    /**
     * Converts bytes to an int
     *
     * @param bytes An array of bytes
     * @param index
     * @returns A int representation of the bytes
     */
    private static int bytesToInt(byte[] bytes, int index) {
        return (bytes[index + 3] & 0xff) << 24 |
                (bytes[index + 2] & 0xff) << 16 |
                (bytes[index + 1] & 0xff) << 8 |
                bytes[index + 0] & 0xff;
    }

    /**
     * Converts bytes to a short
     *
     * @param bytes An array of bytes
     * @param index
     * @returns A short representation of the bytes
     */
    private static short bytesToShort(byte[] bytes, int index) {
        return (short) (((bytes[index + 1] & 0xff) << 8) |
                (bytes[index + 0] & 0xff));
    }

    /**
     * Reads the buffer
     *
     * @param in An InputStream
     * @param buffer An array of bytes
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void readBuffer(InputStream in, byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int bytesToRead = buffer.length;
        while (bytesToRead > 0) {
            int read = in.read(buffer, bytesRead, bytesToRead);
            bytesRead += read;
            bytesToRead -= read;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `awt.image` package is not part of the Android SDK, so this example will not work.

Comment: The subset of Java available in Android doesn't include java.awt.image.BufferedImage, so this code won't work.

Comment: does this mean i won't be able to integrate any java.awt packages into my android app?

Comment: I think some parts of java.awt.font are available.. thats about it though.

Comment: Sorry thought this was a Java question not Android since he was mentioning BufferedImage which I thought was not part of Android.  Mentioned in SO...http://stackoverflow.com/a/5392792/346309

Comment: Maybe you should put your comment in the right place Chris, I think it belongs below my comment in the question...

Comment: YES, you can use java subset on android! Check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140431/android-the-type-java-awt-image-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenced
(I'm late as hell!)

Comment: What about `ResourceRetriever`?

Comment: What about it?  Wasn't around when I wrote this 4 years ago.

Comment: Is there any C# One of this Class?