# Android: The type java.awt.Image cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: android, awt, java

I am using some `java projects in my Android project`. I gave reference to those projects by adding them in `Java Build Path` and `Project References`. After doing this i can access classes of java projects in my android project. but getting this error

```
 The type java.awt.Image cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

what should i do now?? Do i need to add any JRE or something else would help??

Comment: May be, try changing the order of the libraries getting built.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Found solution:**

go to project properties
   `java build pata`->`Add library`

and add `JRE System Library` and click `finish`. Now you can use `java.awt` package :)

Comment: Compiling the code isn't the problem, you won't be able to run it on an Android device, because there is no `java.awt` on dalvik.

Comment: see i am just using Image because my java project is too large to change...i will not use image to show them on imageview like we do in java

Answer (score 2):

You can't use projects that are dependent on `java.awt.Image` or other `awt` packages (except `java.awt.font`) in Android as the dalvik runtime doesn't have these classes in it.

Comment: that is entirely upto you. Check if similar libraries exist for Android, which you are trying to accomplish thru your projects.