# How to set a image (.jpg) in the sd card in android to BufferedImage image

Tags: android

The way i trying to do is this, But i want to set the image to steve.jpg

```
BufferedImage image = null ;
IplImage originalImage = IplImage.createFrom(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like to go through this post... 
[BufferedImage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392695/bufferedimage-in-android/5392792#5392792) which explains why you can't use a BufferedImage in Android.

Hope this helps.