# Using BufferedImage and ImageIO classes in my Android Activity

Tags: android, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am developing an Android App that can do Gamma correction of an image stored in phone. My activity can get the image location, but i cant use the  `BufferedImage`   class and `ImageIO` class in my Application.

I get the following error in Eclipse IDE with ADT plugin..

```
 ImageIO cannot be Resolved

 BufferedImage cannot be Resolved
```

I cannot process  the image . I have an idea of including the java libraries but i don't know how to do this in Android

Here is the Function i need to make it work .

```
private static BufferedImage gammaCorrection(BufferedImage original, double gamma) {

    int alpha, red, green, blue;
    int newPixel;

    double gamma_new = 1 / gamma;
    int[] gamma_LUT = gamma_LUT(gamma_new);

    BufferedImage gamma_cor = new BufferedImage(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), original.getType());

    for(int i=0; i<original.getWidth(); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<original.getHeight(); j++) {

            // Get pixels by R, G, B
            alpha = new Color(original.getRGB(i, j)).getAlpha();
            red = new Color(original.getRGB(i, j)).getRed();
            green = new Color(original.getRGB(i, j)).getGreen();
            blue = new Color(original.getRGB(i, j)).getBlue();

            red = gamma_LUT[red];
            green = gamma_LUT[green];
            blue = gamma_LUT[blue];

            // Return back to original format
            newPixel = colorToRGB(alpha, red, green, blue);

            // Write pixels into image
            gamma_cor.setRGB(i, j, newPixel);

        }

    }

    return gamma_cor;        

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Android is not standard java, it lacks certain classes. AWT is just not there

Answer (score 1):

I think a few Java libraries aren't in Android like the awt

Answer (score 1):

```
     String selectedImagePath;
     ImageView img;
     img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
     Bitmap  yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
     img.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
```

if multiple image than
 you can make

```
        ArrayList<Bitmap> aList = new ArrayList<Bitmap> ();
        aList.add(yourbitmap);
```

than set in imageviews like above using for loop.
because android not provide  BufferedImage class

Comment: Can I use getRGB() , getAlpha() , getWidth(), getType() methods with Bitmap.

Comment: yes you can do all operation on bitmap even you can getRGB value in bitmap.         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669501/how-to-get-rgb-values-of-bitmap-in-android

Comment: I have Edited my question. Added a function using BufferedImage. I need to change it to Bitmap and Please note that I need ImageIO for ImageIO.read(); method and ImageIO.write();

Comment: first read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392695/bufferedimage-in-android you can not use bufferedimage

Answer (score 0):

Try with 
BitmapFactory or Bitmap

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: Those links may answer the question, but it would be better if you could add the important parts from those links in your answer – maybe a short example on how to use the BitmapFactory. One day those links may no longer work and then this answer would be useless.