# Android class reference not found error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class

I'm making an android app. I reference a java project called recognition. When I call a function from it, from my android project, it crashes, with this log:

The java project uses BufferedImage objects and is set to JRE 1.6.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks

EDIT:

I think the problem is `Path` requires 1.7, but android is using 1.6 How can I fix that?

```
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.file.Paths
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at recognition.Recognize.getImage(Recognize.java:168)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at recognition.Recognize.getInitialImage(Recognize.java:80)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at recognition.Recognize.runAnalysis(Recognize.java:46)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at android.arin.SpeciesScreen.onActivityResult(SpeciesScreen.java:131)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5361)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
08-28 21:52:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(21763):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the getImage function

```
private static BufferedImage getImage(String from) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(from);
    File file = path.toFile();

    if (file.exists()) {
        InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(path);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(stream);

        BufferedImage NewBufferedImage = convertToARGB(bufferedImage);
        bufferedImage.flush();
        bufferedImage = NewBufferedImage;

        return bufferedImage;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the android build order:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem:**

```
java.nio.file.Paths
```

The `Paths` class does not exist in android SDK thus giving you `NoClassDefFoundError` `java oracle` and `dalvik java android` have different libraries mostly of them is implemented in android but `BufferedImage` is none of them. Consider using [Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392695/bufferedimage-in-android) instead to get the image.

you can [go here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/package-summary.html) to check the list of class in `java.nio` package in android