# Android Image editing/warping with Java?

Tags: java, android, android-image, jai

Hopefully not making this too vague... but I have been dealing with a lot of image scaling and manipulating with an app I'm working on and wanted to know:

Is it possible/feasible to warp images using java code and if so, is it possible? I have read up on JAI but can't seem to grasp it very well. Is there any form of built in implementation that would work with Android 2.3 or higher?

Any tutorials or examples that someone may have come across would be a great help as I have been researching for a while and can't seem to gain any ground.

End goal: to be able to warp an image (point to point by pixels) in multiple places and then saving the bitmap. This would be processed behind the scenes and show the user the end result.

Answer (score 1):

do you have an example of the kind of warping that you want to do?  It's certainly feasible but you'll probably end up doing pixel-by-pixel manipulation to generate the warped image.

there is a previous discussion here:

[android image processing tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078839/android-image-processing-tutorial)

Comment: Image editing I am hoping to do is related to faces and other objects... stretching parts of the face or other items in an image. Unfortunately I don't have an image of what I would like to do. I have tried to get openCV working but didn't have any luck. Ive never imported another library into a project before so if that is the best route I will have to go back through tutorials again.

Comment: well, ultimately, they're all pixels, and the bitmap library is pretty well developed in Android.  You may have to recreate the specific functionality but it's a matter of examining the input bitmap and creating the output bitmap pixel-by-pixel...