# How to create pincushion distortion effect?

Tags: image-processing, distortion

I want to create barrel and pincushion distortion effect in MTK phones,and get useful helps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1927145/1029950) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6214377/1029950). But i can't understand formulas used in functions of getRadialX、getRadialY and calc_shift although have achieved barrel distortion effect. I hope someone can help me to achieve pincushion effect or explain formulas used in those functions. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199636/formulas-for-barrel-pincushion-distortion/6227310#6227310

Comment: Thanks for you help, but the answer you mentioned is not a good solution, i still try to solve it. Maybe opencv or gimp can help me, thank you.