# Image Distortion in android

Tags: android, image, distortion, warp

How to implement image distortion or image warp by dragging on the screen in android?
I am new to android and I want to make an app like "Photo warp" or "face changer" which distort the image by touching and dragging on screen.
Is there any function or way to implement this feature in app?
I have referenced 
[How to simulate fisheye lens effect by openCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927145/how-to-simulate-fisheye-lens-effect-by-opencv) and 
[fisheye distortion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214377/fisheye-distortion)
and many more but can't get enough information.
I have also referenced "SDK_DIR/samples/android-*/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapMesh.java" but it is not helpful enough for my problem.
Does anyone have any idea or tutorial to implement this feature?