# OpenCV: Simulate FishEye

Tags: c++, opencv, fisheye, distortion

I've read this: [How to simulate fisheye lens effect by openCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927145/how-to-simulate-fisheye-lens-effect-by-opencv) post very good and played around with the code.
I also read the Wiki Article for Distortion(optics) and understood the math behind it.
The only real problem I have, is the calc_shift-function and how the scaling works.
I want to implement fisheye and pincushion distortion in my litte opencv-project for videos. Do I have other options? With built-in functions of opencv i only can correct distortions.
I gonna test http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php?ImageMagick=jb73dabpkumd9niucm1hr5d893 this today.
Best Regards, Moltisanti

Answer (score 0):

you can use intel ipp library with functions like ippiCreateMapCameraUndistort

Comment: perhaps a somewhat more verbose answer would prove better for future readers.